# Vue.js Vuetify , Issue running my first unit test with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js

Herea is my first test :

**Heading.spec.js**

```
    import Vuetify from "vuetify";
    import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";
    import router from "@/router";
    import i18n from "@/locales";
    import Heading from "@/components/Home/Heading.vue";

    describe("Heading.vue", () => {
      let wrapper;

      beforeEach(() => {
        const localVue = createLocalVue()
        localVue.use(router)
        localVue.use(Vuetify)
        localVue.filter("translate", function(value) {
          if (!value) return "";
          value = "lang.views.global." + value.toString();
          return i18n.t(value);
        });

        wrapper = shallowMount(Heading, { localVue: localVue, router, i18n });
      });

      it("should contains default heading", () => {
        console.log ('WRAPPER: ', wrapper)
        // const heading = wrapper.find("h1");
        // expect(heading.text()).toContain("In the heart of Charentes...");
      });
    });
```

when I run it,  get errors with Vuetify ...

console.log

```
    vue-cli-service test:unit

     PASS  tests/unit/Heading.spec.js (11.247s)
      Heading.vue
        ✓ should contains default heading (462ms)

      console.log tests/unit/Heading.spec.js:23
        WRAPPER:  undefined

      console.error node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js:19429
        [Vuetify] Multiple instances of Vue detected
        See https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4068

        If you're seeing "$attrs is readonly", it's caused by this

      console.error node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js:19429
        [Vuetify] Multiple instances of Vue detected
        See https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4068

        If you're seeing "$attrs is readonly", it's caused by this

      console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:589
        [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "src". Expected String, got Object.

        found in

        ---> <VParallax>
               <Heading>
                 <Root>

    Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
    Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
    Snapshots:   0 total
    Time:        17.641s
    Ran all test suites.
```

why do I get Multiple instances of Vue detected ? it's define once in my test ... that's all ?

the test is passing , but I don't undertsand the Vuetify errors....
thanks for feedback

Comment: Here is a reference to the official Vuetify bug:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4964

Comment: what does it say about the design of Vuetify framework if instead of fixing a bug they put a reference to it in their own code?

Answer (score 18):

Solved by not using a localVue:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import router from "@/router";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import i18n from "@/locales";
import Heading from "@/components/Home/Heading.vue";

describe("Heading.vue", () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    Vue.use(router);
    Vue.use(Vuetify);
    Vue.filter("translate", function(value) {
      if (!value) return "";
      value = "lang.views.global." + value.toString();
      return i18n.t(value);
    });

    wrapper = mount(Heading, { router, i18n });
  });

  it('should have a happy ending', () => {
    // You should see all Vuetify components properly rendered
    // as normal HTML tags. For example, <v-flex> should be
    // rendered as <div class="v-flex ...">
    expect(wrapper.contains('div.flex')).toBe(true);

    // Just so that you can visually inspect the rendered html.
    console.log(wrapper.find('.subheading').html());
  });

  it("should contains default heading", () => {
    const h1 = wrapper.find("h1");
    expect(h1.is("h1")).toBe(true);
    expect(h1.text()).toContain("In the heart of Charentes...");
  });
});
```

**Update:** Here is a reference to [the official Vuetify bug](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4964), courtesy of [Tristan Neumann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10206460/tristan-neumann).

Comment: The [guide](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#common-tips) says to use localVue instance instead of polluting the global Vue though

Comment: Yes I know, good point  ... however due to a reported bug in Vuetify in test:units I cannot use a LocalVue ...

Comment: @erwin which reported bug? do you have a link?

Comment: I, too, am quite interested in a link to this issue. I am facing the same problem here and hope your answer will solve it :)

Comment: I'm interested in this too. I'm using a localVue because I'm using a Vuex store, and want to test with Vuetify. My tests do pass, but they give this spurious error. Is there a bug link?

Comment: For anyone who ends up here, the issue is the [#4068](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4068).

Answer (score 4):

There is a way of using localVue in combination with a global registration of the vuetify plugin as beautifully explained in this [comment](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/discussions/4068#discussioncomment-24984) of issue [#4068](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/discussions/4068):

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import component from './my-component.vue'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const localVue = createLocalVue()

describe('module', () => {
  let vuetify
  beforeEach(() => {
    vuetify = new Vuetify()
  })

  it('should do something', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(component, {
      localVue,
      vuetify
    })
  })
})
```

For me this solved my problems with testing my vuetify app.